# intersection with tolerance of non-equal vectors and ID

Tags: r, vector, subset, intersection, assign

I have a question about matching values between two vectors.
Lets say I have a vector and data frame:

```
  data.frame
  value  name                       vector 2
154.0031  A                         154.0084
154.0768  B                         159.0344
154.2145  C                         154.0755
154.4954  D                         156.7758
156.7731  E
156.8399  F
159.0299  G
159.6555  H
159.9384  I
```

Now I want to compare vector 2 with values in the data frame with a defined global tolerance (e.g. +-0.005) that is adjustable and add the corresponding names to vector 2, so I get a result like this:

```
  data.frame
  value  name                       vector 2 name
154.0031  A                         154.0074  A
154.0768  B                         159.0334  G
154.2145  C                         154.0755  B
154.4954  D                         156.7758  E
156.7731  E
156.8399  F
159.0299  G
159.6555  H
159.9384  I
```

I tried to use `intersect()` but there is no option for tolerance in it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This outcome can be achieved through with `outer`, `which`, and subsetting.

```
# calculate distances between elements of each object
# rows are df and columns are vec 2
myDists <- outer(df$value, vec2, FUN=function(x, y) abs(x - y))


# get the values that have less than some given value
# using arr.ind =TRUE returns a matrix with the row and column positions
matches <- which(myDists < 0.05, arr.ind=TRUE)

data.frame(name = df$name[matches[, 1]], value=vec2[matches[, 2]])
name    value
1    A 154.0084
2    G 159.0344
3    B 154.0755
4    E 156.7758
```

Note that this will only return elements of vec2 with matches and will return all elements of df that satisfy the threshold.

to make the results robust to this, use

```
# get closest matches for each element of vec2
closest <- tapply(matches[,1], list(matches[,2]), min)

# fill in the names.
# NA will appear where there are no obs that meet the threshold.
data.frame(name = df$name[closest][match(as.integer(names(closest)),
                                         seq_along(vec2))], value=vec2)
```

Currently, this returns the same result as above, but will return NAs where there is no adequate observation in df.

**data**

Please provide reproducible data if you ask a question in the future. See below.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="value  name
154.0031  A
154.0768  B
154.2145  C
154.4954  D
156.7731  E
156.8399  F
159.0299  G
159.6555  H
159.9384  I")

vec2 <- c(154.0084, 159.0344, 154.0755, 156.7758)
```

Comment: Thanks,that helps a lot! Sry for the data thing, I will provide a suitable dataset for future questions.